# Workaround "flip-flop deprecated" warning in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I invoke Ruby from my shell script like this:

```
ruby -n -e "print if %r($fromre)...%r($tore)" "$@"
```

Since Ruby 2.6, I get the warning

*warning: flip-flop is deprecated*

So it seems that i have to be prepared that the wise high priests of Ruby have decided that this (IMO useful) construct will be completely gone one day.

What would be an easy work-around? Of course I can replace

```
print if %r($fromre)...%r($tore)
```

by

```
inside ||= %r($fromre)
if inside
  print
  inside = false if %r($tore)
end
```

but I wonder whether there is a more concise way to write this.

Comment: The removal is still open / being discussed: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5400. As a user of the flip flop operator, you might want to chime in.

Comment: As far as I know, Rubinius doesn't even implement flip-flop, and so far, nobody seems to have noticed. Also, the Ruby Language Specification does not specify the flip-flop operator, so any code that uses it, is outside the spec anyhow.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It'd be really nice to have a repeatable range operator which would act as a flip-flop at length 2.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : Not quite correct. See [the docs for 2.4](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html) and scroll down to the chapter headed "Flip-Flop". You even find it in the [2.6 docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html), interestingly without any mentioning that this is a deprecated feature.

Comment: @user1934428: Those links are to the documentation of YARV, not the Ruby Specification. In the Ruby Community, there are a couple of things that are considered "the Ruby Specification": the [*ISO Ruby Specification*](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) (doesn't mention flip-flop at all), the book [*The Ruby Programming Language*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516178.do) written by David Flanagan and matz himself (doesn't mention flip-flop at all), the book [*Programming Ruby*](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0) written by Dave Thomas and Andy Hunt (doesn't …

Comment: … mention flip-flop at all), the [RubySpec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/) suite ([mentions flip-flop](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/if_spec.rb#L233-L324) but explicitly [marks it deprecated](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/if_spec.rb#L312-L324)), and "the code that is accepted by all Ruby implementations" (several implementations don't implement flip-flop). Chris Seaton (the lead developer of TruffleRuby) made [an analysis](https://chrisseaton.com/truffleruby/flip-flops/) of flip-flops, by downloading the entire archive of rubygems.org. The result: out …

Comment: … of every single version of every single RubyGem in existence, flip-flop is used in a total of 8 gems a total of 10 times by a total of 5 developers. The full archive contains every version of every gem ever released on rubygems.org, a total of 1.6 billion lines of code, with 69 instances of flip-flop or around 1 in 23 million lines of code. The code to implement flip-flop in TruffleRuby is significantly longer than *all code that uses flip-flop combined*.

Comment: Note also that Chris mentions that this language feature is different from some others such as `$SAFE` levels, continuations, `ObjectSpace`, etc. in that those ones have *deep* impact on the design of the VM and the kinds of optimizations that can be performed, whereas flip-flop is semantically trivial. So, there are *fundamental* reasons not to support one of those semantically invasive features but really no fundamental reasons not to support flip-flop (which is why TruffleRuby chose to implement it, despite the fact it's so rarely used).

Comment: @JörgWMittag : I have seen the discussion bugs.ruby-lang.org, mentioned by Stefan. I can understand that the Ruby developers want to remove a language feature which is troublesome to understand. As a mere user, I just can express that I find it useful. But we don't discuss here, whether or not the deprecation is OK. I just wanted to object your position that it is not described in the language spec.

Comment: @user1934428 _"the Ruby developers want to remove a language feature  [...]"_ – note that the request to remove it came from a user. nobu (Ruby core dev) even [said](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5400#note-21) _"I **STRONGLY** object removal of flip-flop, in "-e" option at least."_.