# How to suppress deprecation warnings?

Tags: ruby, deprecation-warning

(This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648847/workaround-flip-flop-deprecated-warning-in-ruby) question).

How can I suppress deprecation warnings in Ruby, until I find time to update the code? Example: The following command will generated a *flip-flop is deprecated* warning (the command itself is nonsense; I just wanted to provide a minimal, syntactically correct, example):

```
 ruby -v -e '0 if /a/.../b/'
```

I already tried

```
ruby -e '$VERBOSE=nil;0 if /a/.../b/'
```

and, after installing the *warning* gem,

```
 ruby -e 'require "warning";; Warning.ignore(/deprecated/) 0 if /a/.../b/'
```

but the warning is still printed to stderr. I don't want to redirect the whole stderr to the bit bucket, because I don't want to loose important messages.

Comment: based on the comment to the answer below, I have to ask then, why do you need this?

Comment: See the link in my posting, which explains the background of this problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "to the bit bucket" ? Is this flooding logs or something?

Comment: _to the bit bucket_  is another way to say `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Why don't you just fix the code that uses the deprecated class or method? You would need to do that anyway at some point in time if you want to be able to run up-to-date versions of Ruby.

Comment: @spickermann : This also is the topic of the question I linked to. I'm looking for a solution which is at least of similar simplicity than the current one. Also note that I have written above _until I find time to update the code_. And I still hope the Ruby developers will rethink their descision to have this language element deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning is generated by the parser before the code is evaluated. That includes your `Warning.ignore` code, so the config isn't ready when the warning occurs.

You can move that code into a separate file:

```
# warn.rb
require 'warning'
Warning.ignore(/deprecated/)
```

and load it via `-r`:

```
$ ruby -r./warn.rb -e '0 if /a/.../b/'
```

Comment: LoadError: cannot load such file -- warning
NoMethodError: undefined method `ignore' for Warning:Module

Comment: @ArnoldRoa the answer is about the [warning gem](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-warning) the OP mentioned in the question. In vanilla Ruby there's `Warning[:deprecated] = false`, see the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Warning.html)

Answer (score 5):

The flip flop is no longer deprecated.

Answer to the actual question: `ruby -W:no-deprecated`

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I was not aware of it, but now that you are telling it, I found [this](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/01/06/ruby-2-7-revert-flip-flop-operator-deprecation.html) article on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's :

```
ruby -W0 -e 'code'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it filters all the warnings (not only deprecated warnings...)